# Not able to set Firebase Image Uri in Image View

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to set Image from FIrebase to Imageview using Glide but it is showing Error

```
Task<Uri> riversRef = storageReference.child(user.getUid() + "/profile.jpg").getDownloadUrl()
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                            if (uri == null) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "URI IS NULL", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                            Glide.with(getContext()).load(uri).centerCrop().into(imageView);
                        }
                    });
```

And the error is:

> Process: com.root.firebase, PID: 3875
>                                                                    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'boolean android.app.Activity.isDestroyed()' on a null object
>   reference
>                                                                        at
>   com.bumptech.glide.manager.RequestManagerRetriever.assertNotDestroyed(RequestManagerRetriever.java:133)
>                                                                        at
>   com.bumptech.glide.manager.RequestManagerRetriever.get(RequestManagerRetriever.java:125)
>                                                                        at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.with(Glide.java:641)
>                                                                        at
>   com.root.firebase.UploadActivity$2.onSuccess(UploadActivity.java:72)
>                                                                        at
>   com.root.firebase.UploadActivity$2.onSuccess(UploadActivity.java:65)
>                                                                        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzj.run(Unknown Source)
>                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
>                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                        at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
>                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)

Comment: Kindly give me solution; not suggestion

Comment: `getContext()` is null!. Check that. Also you should use a debugger instead of asking people to give you a solution

Comment: well if i know then i would not be asking

Comment: i mean you need to put your effort is knowing whats null. Did you try using a debugger int he first place. Also read the FAQ of the site

Comment: well i know what is Null and i've used a debugger; i just wanted to know which thing was null

Comment: You can see that from the stack trace: `at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.with(Glide.java:641)`

Answer (score 1):

```
Task<Uri> riversRef = storageReference.child(user.getUid() + "/profile.jpg").getDownloadUrl()
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GET IMAGE SUCCESSFUL", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        if (uri == null) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "URI IS NULL", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
               else{         Glide.with(getContext()).load(uri).centerCrop().into(imageView);}
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GET IMAGE FAILED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        // Handle any errors
                    }
                });
```

Comment: what's change in that code?

Comment: else part add because your uri is null and when it load on glide code that time it give error.

Comment: still same error

Comment: have you debug your code what value comes in uri?

Comment: got it... my contex was null... thanks